# Prevent clickable div from being highlighted in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm using a full-screen WebView in an Android app, using API level 15. There are some on/off switches that I'm making clickable with jQuery's `.click` function. The approach works fine, but the click handler causes the button to be highlighted in a transparent shade of blue when the element is tapped, and it's unsightly.

None of these approaches worked to prevent the element from being highlighted:

**CSS Approach**

```
div.pill
{
    outline: none;
}
```

**Click Approach**

```
$("div.pill").click(function(Event)
{
    // ... other code here ...
    Event.stopPropagation();
    Event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

**Mousedown Approach**

```
$("div.pill").mousedown(function(Event)
{
    // ... other code here ...
    Event.stopPropagation();
    Event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Here is an example of the div with a blue highlight:

[image: WebView screenshot]

Does anyone know how to prevent a clickable div from being highlighted when it's clicked?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Put below code in the CSS file:

`-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Thanks, Drax! I'll accept your answer once the system lets me.

Comment: because with that it identifies the web engine and apply the properties.

Answer (score 11):

On galaxy devices "-webkit-tap-highlight-color" only works with

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
```

Comment: So, you can set it to transparent and set the desired background on focus pseudo-class